# Finding Null values among mixed object types Python

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have the following list from which I want to identify values that are null:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> MyList=['Apple',np.nan,4,100.4]
>>> MyList
['Apple', nan, 4, 100.4]
>>>
```

Because of the fact that my list contains a string, the function `np.isnan()` will not work. Therefore, I instead write a function that first checks if the item is a float and then checks whether it is null.

```
>>> def isnull(x):
...     if type(x)==np.float:
...         return np.isnan(x)
...     else:
...         return False
... 
>>> [isnull(x) for x in MyList]
[False, True, False, False]
>>>
```

Is this the best appoach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably better off catching the `TypeError`:

```
def isnull(x):
    try:
        return np.isnan(x)
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

This isn't a huge improvement, but I think most pythonistas cringe a bit when they see `type(something) == some_type`...

Answer (score 0):

You have numpy array of the dtype=object. You might want to consider coerce it first using pandas to native (float64) type, something along the line

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_numeric(MyList, errors='coerce')
```

Specify errors='coerce' to force strings that can't be parsed to a numeric value to become NaN. Column type would be dtype: float64, and then `np.isnan()` check should work, and it would be faster as well